Why I am requiring tiny learning rate to overfit the model?
I am trying to train LSTM model on a timeseries data with 1.6 million records. I have taken window size of 200.
Initially I tried to overfit the model (train data = test data) on tiny dataset (few thousand records). I observed that if I take base LR > 0.00005 (say 0.005 or 0.0005), the loss goes down quickly but it plateaus at higher loss, even if I decrease it in steps.  I was able to overfit well only when I started with base LR 0.00005. I believe the reason behind this is that my sensor readings range in tiny values. Here are three records:
 0.23760258454545455,-0.22289974636363638,0.0001035681818190329,-0.04648843152272728,0.050574934999999994,0.07726843131818183
 0.22356182786363635,-0.3411078932272727,-0.20997647727272656,0.10069696159090907,0.000854025636363637,0.020162423527272724
 0.28690914204545453,-0.1688149386363636,0.21814179090909178,0.11453165154545455,0.11816517982272727,-0.011788583654545453

The smallest magnitude value above is 0.0001035681818190329, and largest magnitude value is 0.11816517982272727.
Below are screenshots that show training and validation loss and correspodning learning rates for three runs. As can be seen in screenshots, green and brown runs  start with LR 0.005, reducing in step to 0.0005 and 0.00005. But they both plateue at higher training and validation loss than grey colored run which used constant LR 0.00005. Also when I visualized the output predictions, they were very accurate for grey runs, while for green and brown, they very very off from groud truths. I got even better results when I further decreased LR to 0.000005 and 0.0000005 in steps. (I step down the learning rate only when current LR did not improve testing loss for 7 epochs.)

Q.  I guess to overfit space defined by such small values, I might be requiring tiny learning rate 0.000005, and higher learning rate does not work for such space defined by such small values. Am I correct with this understanding?
PS: I tried standardizing the values, but it did gave very very bad predictions, for same training configuration. Will love if someone enlighten me why this is happening. I believe the raw sensor values provide more meaningful / realistic / ground truth data than the scaled one, thats why not standardizing give better results?
